# Redux Persist Transform Encrypt: baseReducer is not a function

Tags: encryption, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I'm able to `persist` my data in `localStorage` across all pages as shown in the image below. I've created two `reducers` to handle **persisted data** for **public(anonymous users)** & **private(registered users)** usages.

[image]

But unfortunately got this error (shown in the image below) when populating **codes** from `redux-persist-transform-encrypt`

[image]

Here I'm using these **packages** in **NextJS** project framework:

- `@redux/toolkit`
- `redux`
- `redux-persist`
- `redux-persist-tansform-encrypt`

Here is my `store.js` located in `/src/redux/store.js`

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  FLUSH, PAUSE,
  PERSIST, persistReducer, PURGE,
  REGISTER, REHYDRATE
} from 'redux-persist'
import { encryptTransform } from 'redux-persist-transform-encrypt'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import globalDynamicPrivate from './slices/globalDynamicPrivate'
import globalDynamicPublic from './slices/globalDynamicPublic'
import { albumSlice } from './slices/album'
import { geoSlice } from './slices/geo'
import { postSlice } from './slices/post'

const encryptor = {
  transforms: [
    encryptTransform({
      secretKey: 'my-super-secret-key',
      onError: function (error) {
        // Handle the error.
        console.log('Error: ', error)
      },
    }),
  ],
}

const persistglobalDynamicPublicConfig = {
  key: 'globalDynamicPublic',
  storage,
}

const persistglobalDynamicPrivateConfig = {
  key: 'globalDynamicPrivate',
  storage,
}

const reducers = combineReducers({
  globalDynamicPublic: persistReducer(
    persistglobalDynamicPublicConfig, 
    { 
      transforms: encryptor
    },
    globalDynamicPublic
  ),
  globalDynamicPrivate: persistReducer(
    persistglobalDynamicPrivateConfig, 
    { 
      transforms: encryptor
    },
    globalDynamicPrivate
  ),
  [albumSlice.reducerPath]: albumSlice.reducer, // RTK Query
  [geoSlice.reducerPath]: geoSlice.reducer, // RTK Query
  [postSlice.reducerPath]: postSlice.reducer, // RTK Query
})

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
    }
  }).concat(albumSlice.middleware).concat(geoSlice.middleware).concat(postSlice.middleware)
})
```

These are my **global** `reducers`

- global public data located in `/src/redux/slices/globalDynamicPublic.js`

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  something: 'this is something',
}

export const globalDynamicPublicSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'globalDynamicPublic',
  initialState,
  // // The reducers field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
    setglobalDynamicPublicState: (state, action) => {
      state[action.payload?.name] = action.payload?.value
    }
  }
})

export const { setglobalDynamicPublicState } = globalDynamicPublicSlice.actions;

// The function below is called a selector and allows us to select a value from
// the state. Selectors can also be defined inline where they're used instead of
// in the slice file. For example: useSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter.value)
export const selectglobalDynamicPublicState = (state) => state.globalDynamicPublic

export default globalDynamicPublicSlice.reducer;
```

- global public data located in `/src/redux/slices/globalDynamicPrivate.js`

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {}

export const globalDynamicPrivateSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'globalDynamicPrivate',
  initialState,
  // // The reducers field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
    setglobalDynamicPrivateState: (state, action) => {
      state[action.payload?.name] = action.payload?.value
    }
  }
})

export const { setglobalDynamicPrivateState } = globalDynamicPrivateSlice.actions;

// The function below is called a selector and allows us to select a value from
// the state. Selectors can also be defined inline where they're used instead of
// in the slice file. For example: useSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter.value)
export const selectglobalDynamicPrivateState = (state) => state.globalDynamicPrivate

export default globalDynamicPrivateSlice.reducer;
```

I've double checked how I `import` & `export` data whether using `export default` or `export const`and it seems to be true (Since most of threads out there addressing this issue).